# Small lemma on moving up multiplicative inverses of powers needs explanation

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

I am reading about a lemma that shows how to lift up a multiplicative inverse. I.e. if we  know that $3\cdot 3 \equiv 1 \pmod {2^3}$ then we know that $3\cdot 43 \equiv \pmod {2^6}$
To go from $\pmod {2^3}$ to $\pmod {2^6}$ we use the formula:
if $xy \equiv 1\pmod {p^e}$ then $xz \equiv 1\pmod {p^{2e}}$ where $z = y- yrp^e$ and $r$ is the from $xy = 1 + rp^e$
There are two parts I don't understand and would like some help.

1. First of all, is such a proof usually "discovered" from the result? I mean if I work backwards and replacing I can see that I can get back to $xy \equiv 1 \pmod {p^e}$.
   And I can apply the formula to solve a problem of this type. But I don't have any intuitive "feel" of that $y- yrp^e$ that we multiply $x$ instead of $y$ to move to the higher power i.e. from $p^e$ to $p^{2e}$. Is there a way to understand this better?
2. The lemma as part of the steps/proof sates that:

> We need a $z \equiv y \pmod {p^e} \implies z = y + tp^e$ and we need
> $xz \equiv 1\pmod {p^{2e}} \implies x(y + tp^e) \equiv 1 \pmod
> > {p^{2e}}$. Since $xy = 1 + rp^e$ we know that $1 + rp^e + xtp^e \equiv
> > 1 \pmod {p^{2e}}$. Since $xy \equiv 1 \pmod p^e$ setting $t = -yr$
> solves the congruence

The last sentence is what I don't understand. We want to solve $1 + rp^e + xtp^e \equiv 1 \pmod {p^{2e}} \implies 1 + (r + xt)p^e \equiv 1 \pmod {p^{2e}}$
But $xy \equiv 1$ in $\pmod p^e$ and not by $\pmod {p^{2e}}$so how can we solve it like it says using the inverse?

Comment: $a\equiv b\pmod m\implies a=mx+b$ remember.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee: Yes but how does it help in the specific stumbling blocks?

Comment: Assume $m=p^e$ then the result is $b+ (x\bmod p^e)\cdot p^e$ modulo $p^{2e}$

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee: If I assume $m = p^e$ then $a = p^ex + b \implies a \equiv b \pmod {p^e}$ but with what steps did you go to that last formula?

Comment: A multiple of $p^e$ is congruent to it's multiplier modulo $p^e$  times $p^e$ because $p^e\cdot p^e=p^{2e}$

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee: "A multiple of $p^e$ is congruent to its multiplier modulo $p^e$". Does that statement mean $kp^e \equiv k \pmod {p^e}$?

Comment: No. It means $$k\equiv c\pmod {p^e}\implies k\cdot p^e\equiv c\cdot p^e\pmod {p^{2e}}$$

Answer (score 1):

If $t=-yr$ then $$1+rp^e+xtp^e=1+rp^e+(x(-yr))p^e= 1+rp^e-rp^e$$ that's the last line explained .

Comment: My question for that was why is the multiplicative inverse valid which is a precondition for $t = yr$? Based on your comments, is it because: $xy \equiv 1 \pmod {p^e} \implies xy = 1 + kp^e \implies xyp^e = 1\cdot p^e + kp^ep^e \implies xyp^e \equiv 1\cdot p^e\cdot kp^{2e} \implies xy \equiv 1 \pmod {p^{2e}}$     since we are cancelling out $p^e$? Otherwise I understand that substitution you mention.

Comment: The multiplicative inverse mod a power is congruent to one of the solutions mod the base.

Comment: Could you give a concrete example of the meaning of your last statement? Also are the steps I mention in my previous comment to end up with $xy\equiv 1 \pmod {p^2e}$ correct?

Comment: $3\cdot 3\equiv 1\pmod 8$ and that implies that the inverse of $3$ modulo $8^m$ is $3$ modulo $8$ for $64$ we then have $3,11,19,27,35,43,51,59$ our possible cases. This is just a use of $mx+b=dz+b$ where $d\mid m$

Comment: "that implies that the inverse of 3 modulo $8^m$ is $3$ modulo $8$". I don't understand this sentence. $3$ modulo $8$ is $3$ for all powers of $2.$ I.e. $3 \equiv 3 \pmod 8$ and $3 \equiv 3 \pmod {16}$ and $3 \equiv 3 \pmod {32}$ $3 \equiv 3 \pmod {64}$. I am misreading something?

Comment: What remainder modulo $8$ does $64x+r$ have if $r=3,11,19,27,35,43,51,59$ ? $1$ class modulo $8$ turns into $8$  classes modulo $64$

Comment: First of all I just realized that the approach in my first comment is wrong. Because for that to be valid and go from $xyp^e \equiv 1\cdot p^e \cdot kp^{2e} \implies xy \equiv 1 \pmod p^{2e}$ then $p^e$ has to be the inverse of $p^e$ otherwise I can not cancel out $p^e$ from both sides right?

Comment: For $r = 3 \implies 64x +3  \equiv 3 \pmod 8$. For $r = 11 \implies 64x + 11 \equiv 3 \pmod 8$. For $r = 19 = 64x + 19 \equiv 3 \pmod 8$. So all these are $[3]$ in modulo $8$. So from a lower power when we go up we go to more remainders. But I don't get the wider idea of how this helps here

Comment: Because it is strictly one of these remainders that will be the inverse!

Comment: So if the inverse `\pmod 8` belongs to the congruence class $3$ I think I understand that when going to $64$ since it is a multiple of $8$ the inverse has to be one of the congruence classes that $3$ is "mapped" when going from modulo $8$ to modulo $64$. But is there no possibility that there is an inverse modulo $64$ that does not belong to that "mapping"?

Comment: The inverse if it exist is unique ...

Comment: Ah I see. The thing is that so far, I get what you are saying that we are moving up the power from e.g. $3$ to $3,11,19,27$ etc. But the formula I mention in the post gives us directly what is the inverse in the higher power without needing to check any of the others in the sequence i.e. $11,19$ etc. The inverse is $y - yrp^e$ and we ignore the rest, but I don't really understand it how it works. $3\cdot 3 = 1 + 1(8)$. So $y - yrp^e = 3 - 3\cdot 1 \cdot 8 = -21 \equiv 11 \pmod {16}$ And indeed $3\cdot 11 \equiv 1 \pmod{16}$. How does that work exactly?

Comment: $x(-yr)\equiv -r\pmod{p^e}\implies x(-yr)p^e\equiv -rp^e\pmod {p^{2e}}$  which cancels the $rp^e$ in $xy=rp^e+1$

Comment: I didn't understand the last sentence: "which cancels the $rp^e$ in xy = rp^e + 1 ...". What/how is it cancelled? I can see that this is consistent to the example above, but what is the intuition? How did you notice/correlate that $x(-yr) \equiv -r$?

Comment: Associativity of multiplication gives $-(xy)r\equiv -(1)r$

Comment: I see. And what is cancelled? Is  $x(-yr)p^e=-rp^e+np^{2e} \implies -rp^e = -rp^e + npe^{2e} \implies 0=np^{2e}$ which is not helpful. So how do we use that? Especially since $x(-y)k\equiv -k \pmod {p^e}$ for all $k$. Or $x(y)k\equiv k \pmod {p^e}$. So how do we use this information to map to the specific inverse in the higher power?

Comment: @Bill Dubuque can you link him to the basics ...

Comment: @RoddyPacPhee: the part that I am not clear is "which cancels the $rp^e$ in $xy = rp^e +1$"

Comment: So basic cancellation properties, as $-rp^e$ cancels $rp^e$ .

Comment: But this statement is basically what I am asking. Which formula are you referring that the cancellation happens? You note "which cancels the $rp^e$ in $xy = rp^e + 1$. Do we multiply that with $-r$? I don't understand what you mean here

Comment: I am sorry if my question seems trivial. Somehow I am stuck understanding what you mean there.

Comment: Request: learn basic arithmetic first. https://www.purplemath.com/

Comment: May be you are right. To be honest (and I apologize if I sound critical) your comments are always very succinct and kind of cryptic to me. They are very helpful and insightful. It is just that only after further probing I can understand what you are trying to convey. In this case I have the impression you have a specific context in mind that I can't see and the problem is not the actual rules you are using.

Comment: What specifically in that link you share you think I should review?

Comment: Things like $-rp^e+rp^e=0$

Comment: I know that and I already used that property in this comment https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4265212/small-lemma-on-moving-up-multiplicative-inverses-of-powers-needs-explanation/4266222?noredirect=1#comment8879723_4266149. My confusion is how that relates to how we map directly to the inverse in the higher power

Comment: It cancels and leaves the $1$ alone ... The remainder we are looking for.

Comment: I see now where the misunderstanding was, you were referring to the last part of the equation you wrote in your answer that leaves $1$ ie. $1+rp^e -rp^e$ while I was confused as to how can we use the fact that $xy \equiv 1$ in a lower power to achieve that cancellation. After reading again the comments I realized that if $xy \equiv 1 \pmod {p^e} \implies xy \equiv {1, 1 + p^e, 1 + 2p^e ...} \pmod {p^{2e}}$ and that allows that substitution. Thanks for your help

Comment: Basically it was not clear to me why the proof focuses on $r + xt \equiv 0 \pmod {p^e}$ instead of $r + xt \equiv 0 \pmod {p^{2e}}$ and uses $xy \equiv 1 \pmod {p^e}$ instead of $xy \equiv 1 + kp^e \pmod {p^{2e}}$ but the latter leads to dead end. So I think the idea is we use $xy \equiv 1 \pmod {p^e}$ which leads to $r + xt \equiv 0 \pmod {p^e}$ which maps to $0 + np^e$ which leads to the cancellation of terms

Comment: I hope the reasoning about the usage in the previous comment is strictly correct

Answer (score 1):

So, the multiplicative inverses are special and unique for fields. The multiplicative inverse of $3$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{2^3}$ is $3$ since $3\cdot 3 \equiv_8 1$. 3 is it's own inverse, an idempotent.

Now when you "lift" the power $3$ is no longer it's own inverse. This is because we have "more room". $3\cdot 3 = 9$ and in $\mathbb{Z}_{2^6}$ we have $9 \not\equiv_{2^6} 1$.

So the equation $3\cdot 3 \equiv_{2^6} 1$ is false(and it is clear since it is $9$).

So you have to find the multiplicative inverse of 3. What is it in now? $3x \equiv_{2^6} 1$. Solve for $x$. What is $x$? $x = \frac{1}{3}$. But we have no fractions in $\mathbb{Z}$! Well, lets write it nicer $x = 3^{-1}$. Clearly then $3\cdot 3^{-1} = 1$.

Well, $\mathbb{Z}_{2^3}$ relates to $\mathbb{Z}_{2^6}$ and so you can use information about each to help with figuring out stuff from the other. They actually relate quite nicely.

Remember in $\mathbb{Z}_{2^3}$ we had $3^{-1} = 3$ but we also have $3^{-1} = 3 + 2^3 k$ for any $k$, clearly. I.e., $3^{-1} \equiv_{2^3} 3 + 2^3 k \equiv_{2^3} 3$

When we "lift" the exponent we end up reducing the possible $k$ values, it can't be any $k$ value any more like it was. Now we have $3^{-1} \equiv_{2^6} 3 + 2^3 k$ and this equation isn't true for all $k$ any more.

BUT we still have $3\cdot 3^{-1} = 1$ and so $3\cdot 3^{-1} = 3\cdot(3 + 2^3 k) = 9 + 3\cdot 2^3k$ and we want this to be true for $\mathbb{Z}_{2^6}$ so we have $9 + 3\cdot 2^3k \equiv_{2^6} 1$.

But this is the thing, what I've said also hold true for $\mathbb{Z}_{2^4}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{2^5}$. They too will have $3^{-1}$ as multiplicative inverses. It is 11 in both because $3\cdot 11 = 33 \equiv_{2^{4|5}} 1$. This further limits the possibilities of $k$ all down to 1. In fact, it is *always* 1 possibility.

Effectively we have the equations

$3\cdot 3^{-1} = 3\cdot(3 + 2^3 k_1) \equiv_{2^3} 1$

$3\cdot 3^{-1} = 3\cdot(3 + 2^3 k_2) \equiv_{2^4} 1$

$3\cdot 3^{-1} = 3\cdot(3 + 2^3 k_3) \equiv_{2^5} 1$

$3\cdot 3^{-1} = 3\cdot(3 + 2^3 k_4) \equiv_{2^6} 1$

But all those $k_i$'s are connected since $k_{j+1} \not= 2^m k_j$ where m would make the result invalid. E.g., $k_2\not= 2k_1$ else we could have $9 \equiv_{16} 1$ which is invalid. So ultimately a system of equations results with a unique solution and this solution will ultimately give us the multiplicative inverse in the "lifted" field.

As you can easily see the inverses are $3, 11, 11, 42$ or $3, 3 + 2^3, 3 + 2^3, 3 + 2^3 + 2^5$. Those $2^m$'s are annihilated when we modulo by  $2^{<m}$. Since 2^4 is missing we end up with the same inverse. As you lift up you will get a series for $3^{-1} = 3 + \sum b_k 2^k$ and this turns out to be the binary expansion of $\frac{1}{3}$. It almost could be nothing else!

So $\mathbb{Z}_{p^m}$'s inverses essentially are just truncated forms of $\mathbb{Q}$. How nice is that!

Comment: When you say: "$3^{-1} \equiv_{2^6} 3 + 2^3 k$ and this equation isn't true for all $k$ any more". Why is this the form for the inverse in mod $2^6$? I didn't understand this

Comment: @Jim So, the inverse in all groups is represented by $3^{-1}$. The issue is that you don't know what element in the group this represents. In $\mathbb{Q}$ it is represented by $\frac{1}{3}$ but in $\mathbb{Z}_n$ it depends. Now for the question, clearly $3^{-1} \equiv_{2^3}  3 + 2^3 k$ and it is true for any $k$. This is not true in $\mathbb{Z}_{2^6}$ because when you mod $2^6$ there are terms that won't "cancel out" as they did before, more precisely: $3^{-1} \equiv_{2^3}  3 + 2^3 (k + a2 + b2^2 + c2^3 + d2^4 + \cdots)$. So when we "go up the ladder" more terms enter in.

Comment: What you have to understand is that when you reduce $\mathbb{Z}_{2^6}$ down to $\mathbb{Z}_{2^3}$ it's not arbitrary. Whatever the inverse is in $\mathbb{Z}_{2^6}$ you can $mod\; 2^3$ it and that must be the inverse in $\mathbb{Z}_{2^3}$. This is because $\mathbb{Z}_{2^3} < \mathbb{Z}_{2^6}$.  So there is a precise relationship between them. E.g., take $\mathbb{Z}_{2^1} < \mathbb{Z}_{2^2}$. $\{0,1\}$ vs $\{0,1,2,3\}$ $mod\; 2$ the latter you get the former. So $3$ is it's own inverse here too. In fact, $3 = 1 + 2^1$,our form really is $3^{-1} \equiv 1 + 2^1 + 0 \cdot 2^2 + 1\cdot 2^3 + \cdots$

Comment: Rather than working from the top down you should see it from the bottom up. If we have $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ then $\mathbb{Z}_{p^2}$ is precisely p "copies" of $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$. The cosets are all based on $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ and essentially duplicate structure. $\mathbb{Z}_{p^3}$ is $p$ copies of $\mathbb{Z}_{p^2}$ or $p^2$ copies of $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$. The inverses can be shuffled around as we go up the chain but it, in fact, happens in a very predictable manner because ultimately it must behave according to how it works in $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: This helps, I understand that when we go down it is unique, when we go up we get more. The post though is about a small formula that maps to the exact inverse as we go to a higher power without needing to check the others. E.g. The inverse is $y -yrp^e$ and we ignore the rest, but I don't really understand it how it works. $3⋅3=1+1(8)$. So $y -yrp^e = 3−3⋅1⋅8=−21≡11(mod16)$ And indeed 3⋅11≡1(mod16). But we ignored the others in the set that $3$ from mod 8 corresponds when we go to mod 16

Comment: @Jim So, The thing to understand is that $Z_4$ = $Z_2 * Z_2$ and $Z_8 = Z_4 * Z4$, etc. Here $*$ is a sort of "duplication". $Z_4 = \{0,1,2,3\}$ but in reality it's $\{0 + Z_2, 1 + Z_2\}$. The inverse of $0$ is $0$ and $1$ is $1$ in $Z_2$. So the inverse of $0 + Z_2$ is $0 + Z_2$. So when you look at $Z_8 = \{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$ it's $\{0 + Z_2, 1 + Z_2, 2 + Z_2, 3 + Z_2\} = \{0 + Z_4, 1 + Z_4\}$. The latter form looks just like it did for the $Z_4$ case.  This creates a self-similar structure(a fractal like object). If you write this structure down you end up with a binary tree.

Comment: The inverse of some element then can be followed down the tree or up the tree depending on how you wrote it(from $Z_{2^n}$ at the root or $Z_2$. The inverse of some element then will either go left or right depending on with coset it is in and this is a binary sequence. The point here is that the binary representation is key. Any integer in $Z_{2^n}$ can be written in binary. So write your y in binary form and you end up with a binary sequence $\sum a_k 2^k$. Note that $-$ can be converted in to $+$.

Comment: The thing to note is that you are specifically dealing with a sub case of what I'm doing. You are looking at the square of the $p^k$-power. This allows you to simplify things significantly. When I get a little more time I'll extend my answer for that case.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, they are very helpful. In the 3rd to the last comment your write: "The inverse of 0 is 0 and 1 is 1 in 2." Does $0$ have an inverse? It is $0\cdot 0 \equiv 0 \pmod Z^2$ right?

Comment: Also why do you mention in the answer " this equation isn't true for all  any more."? It seems to me $k$ would be valid but the number would be a different conguence class

Comment: And I really find the description you do about the relation with $Z_6$ and $Z_3$ as trees and binary expansions. Do you have a suggestion of a good source I can read about this aspect?

Comment: @Jim, Ok, I added the explanation of how your lemma works and I tried to be as clear as possible. Yes, you are right. I wasn't meaning to use it in that sense. I was being sloppy with notation and mixing addition and multiplication. I meant to use '*' and that it means "duplicate"(whatever that is, basically concatenation).

Comment: When we are inside a c.c., the multiplier is irrelevant(that is kinda the point) and sometimes it is irrelevant outside depending on what we are doing.  E.g., sometimes when we are working inside a single c.c. we might include the expansion even though it is irrelevant. Other times we might include without knowing the multiplier but in the end everything works out. But in some cases we have to be sure that it is actually a specific value. In my answer this is the case as we move from $p^e$ to $p^{2e}$ we have to track the multiplier. I think the answer should explain what I mean better.

Comment: As far as the tree's go, I'm not sure. The fundamental theorem of finite albelian groups essentially connects these... or anything that has any factoring or parsing one will get tree's. Because a factor group will split the group in to n equal cosets of size $|G|/|H|$ we can write the tree for that. But the normal subgroup itself is factorable then one can continue the tree and so on. This is the same as integer factorization and how their tree's work. The only diff here is that for $2^k$ one ends up with a tree of depth k with $Z_2$ as the leafs and one can work up the hierarchy.

Comment: I'm probably making it sound more complex than it is. The only thing is that paths these regular tree's can be represented as decimals and this can then have interesting relationships to problem one can use them in. E.g., if we have an element $x \in Z_{2^100}$ then x can be represented as a binary string 100 digits long or as a terminating binary decimal or, of course, equivalently, as some number in another base. The idea I was getting at is that since we are dealing with a subgroup, there will be mapping between it and the parent group... which your lemma deals with and shows that relation.

Comment: "When we are inside a c.c" what is a `c.c`?

Answer (score 1):

First, a non-constructive proof:

Given $xy \equiv_{p^e} 1$ solve for z in $xz \equiv_{p^{2e}} 1$ then

$z = y−yrp^e$ where $xy=1+rp^e$

To show this is true, multiply the first equation by $x$:
$xz = xy(1 - rp^e) = (1 + rp^e)(1 - rp^e) = 1 - r^2p^{2e}$

Clearly then $xz \equiv_{p^{2e}} (1 - r^2 p^{2e}) \equiv_{p^{2e}} 1$

This at least shows the formula for $z$ is consistent with what we desire. Note that this equation specifically deals with the square of the power because it's essentially based off the fact that $1 - x^2$ can be factored in to linear factors. (but of course it will work for any $e$ so one can chain this)

This doesn't say why we must choose the specific $r$ though but that should be clear because any $r$ works for the 1st equation but it then must be consistent with the 2nd as not $r$ will work in when we "lift" to the larger module.

So how does one go about finding this?

1. Suppose you know $xy \equiv_{p^e} 1$ and you want to find the $z$ that makes $xz \equiv_{p^{2e}} 1$ true. Well, you have 2 equations with 1 unknown so it should generally have a solution(assuming the first does but we are given it so it must).
2. The first equation is just $xy = 1 + rp^e$ for *any* $r\in\mathbb{Z}$. Notice, this is your "you must find $r$" part of the condition to find $z$ but here it can be anything, it only gets restricted due to the next step. Note that $r$ is actually a single value once we move outside the module so it is no longer arbitrary in our problem.
3. The second equation says, similarly, $xz = 1 + sp^{2e}$. It should be clear all we have is really the first equation to work with so we must use that. It might not be all that clear why, but clearly if we multiply by $y$ then $yxz = y + ysp^{2e}$. $s$ is arbitrary because we never go outside of $\mathbb{Z}_{p^{2e}}$.

So it should be pretty easy to see that we have

$yxz = (1 + tp^{e})z = y(1 + sp^{2e})$

Notice $yxz$ and how it is special. Depending on how we associate the result we can get to use either of our original equations: $(yx)z = y(xz)$. Associativity(and commutativity) allows us to get two different representations for the same quantity and it's precisely the two representations we have available.

Now we would like to isolate $z$. This can be done quite easily by multiplying by $1 - rp^{e}$,

$(1 - rp^{2e})z = y(1 + sp^{2e})(1 - rp^{e}) = (1 - rp^{e} + sp^{2e} - srp^{3e})y$

But clearly

$z \equiv_{p^{2e}} (1 - rp^{e})y$

which solves for $z$.

So, really, I didn't do anything complex. I used the two original equations, I wrote them in terms of their equivalent expansion. I was able to connect them by simply multiplying the latter by $y$ so I could get the first. I then simply multiplied by the conjugate factor which, because I knew I was going to be in $\mathbb{Z}_{p^{2e}}$ that the factors would cancel out and leave me with a nice representation.

E.g.,

$14\cdot 9 \equiv_{5^3} 1$

$14\cdot z \equiv_{5^6} 1$

$xy = 126 = 1 + r5^3 \rightarrow r = 1$

So $z \equiv_{5^6} 9\cdot (1 - 1\cdot 5^6) \equiv_{5^6} -1116 \equiv_{5^6} 14509$

Or similarly,

$9\cdot 14 \equiv_{5^3} 1$

$9\cdot z \equiv_{5^6} 1$

$xy = 126 = 1 + r5^3 \rightarrow r = 1$

So $z \equiv_{5^6} 14\cdot (1 - 1\cdot 5^6) \equiv_{5^6} -1736\equiv_{5^6} 13889$

Comment: $yxz = (1 + tp^{e})z = y(1 + sp^{2e})$ you did not define where that $t$ comes from. I suppose the meaning is that it is the same form as lower power but different constant?

Comment: "This can be done quite easily by multiplying by $1 - rp^{e}$," I lost you on the next step and whats going on there

Comment: if you have time to check my last comment I would be grateful